# Kotlin Jetpack Compose NavGraph Viewmodel Testing

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I would like to be able to update a viewmodel with values I want. I am not sure if it is possible the current way I am doing things.

Example: I have tried to create the viewmodel in the setup block of the test to set the name field to "Hello from test!", but when the viewmodel is used later on, it does not have the correct data.

I am open to alternative approaches, the reason I chose this one is I can use the same viewmodel across the entire navGraph and the viewmodel is created and destroyed as needed.

Test Class

```
class SectionOneTest {
    @get: Rule
    val composeRule = createAndroidComposeRule<MainActivity>()

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        composeRule.activity.setContent {
            val navController = rememberNavController()

            val viewModel = hiltViewModel<SectionOneViewModel>()
            viewModel.formState = viewModel.formState.copy(
                name = "Hello for test!"
            )

            NavGraphQuestionTheme {
                NavHost(
                    navController = navController,
                    startDestination = NavGraphs.SectionOne.route
                ) {
                    sectionOneNavGraph(
                        navController = navController
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun assert_name_text_is_not_empty() {
        composeRule.onNodeWithText("Name").assertExists()
        composeRule.onNodeWithTag("name-textField").assertExists()
        composeRule.onNodeWithTag("name-textField").assertTextEquals("Name", "Hello for test!")
    }
}
```

NavGraph

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.sectionOneNavGraph(
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    navigation(
        route = NavGraphs.SectionOne.route,
        startDestination = Screens.SectionOneScreenOne.route
    ) {
        pageOneComposable(
            navController = navController,
        )
        pageTwoComposable(
            navController = navController,
        )
        pageThreeComposable(
            navController = navController,
        )
        pageFourComposable(
            navController = navController,
        )
    }
}
```

Page One Composable

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.pageOneComposable(
    navController: NavHostController,
) {
    composable(
        route = Screens.SectionOneScreenOne.route
    ) { navBackStackEntry ->
        PageOneScreen(
            viewModel = navBackStackEntry.sharedViewModel(navController = navController),
            onNavigateScreen = {
                navController.navigateSingleTopTo(it)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

sharedViewModel (Note, used to get already existing viewmodel or create a new one if it doesnt exist.)

```
@Composable
inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> NavBackStackEntry.sharedViewModel(navController: NavController): T {
    val navGraphRoute = destination.parent?.route ?: return hiltViewModel()
    val parentEntry = remember(this) {
        navController.getBackStackEntry(navGraphRoute)
    }
    return hiltViewModel(parentEntry)
}
```

Full project source code: https://github.com/Public-orgs/NavGraphQuestion